# LI background image shows behind li > img

Tags: html, css, image

So, I have this html structure:

```
<li class="block1">
     <a title="Block 1 Title" href="get/wzTZKKrI1kQ">
          <img height="150" width="200" alt="Block 1 Title" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-170-230-2.jpg">
          <span>Block 1 Title</span>
     </a>
</li>
```

And this .css code:

```
#home #results li{
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align: left;
  /*background: #E1D4C0;*/
}
#home #results li.block1{ 
  background: #E1D4C0 url("../imgs/bg/lp-bg.png") no-repeat top center;
  z-index: 1
}
```

But for some reason the **#home #results li.block1** background img shows behind html img/**#home #results li img** / `#home #results li.block1`'s background image shows behind `<li><a><img>`

Why is that happening? I have tried z-index and no success

Edit:
screenshot: http://awesomescreenshot.com/068s3wo8e

I've managed to fix it, check out my answer below.

Comment: Are you asking why a background image is showing up behind an image that is within the element containing it?

Comment: I don't see how this is possible. The z-index property does not apply to an element's background image and a background image cannot appear in front of any of it's children (by default).

Comment: Weird, I could swear that I have done it... placing an image with css over a html img. Any workaround to make it show up before the html img you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by doing:

Html:

```
<li class="block1">
     <a title="Block 1 Title" href="get/wzTZKKrI1kQ">
        ---->> <div></div> <<----
          <img height="150" width="200" alt="Block 1 Title" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-170-230-2.jpg">
          <span>Block 1 Title</span>
     </a>
</li>
```

css:

```
 #home #results li{
      float: left;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
      display: inline;
      text-align: left;
      position: relative;
      background: #E1D4C0;
   }
   #home #results li.block1 div{ 
      width: 226px;
      height: 238px;
      background: url("../imgs/apis/lp-bg.png") no-repeat top center;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 10;
      left: 0px;
      top: -7px;
   }
```

Explain:

I added an empty div  **inside a** tag (note: inside so it makes the image that overlays the li **clickable**) than I added a `position: relative;` to the li itself, in order to have it as reference for `li.block1 div` and set it with `width: 226px; height: 238px; position: absolute; z-index: 10`.

The width and height are the image's values that will stay on top, and position and z-index to make it stay on top of li, the rest are just rules to make it fit in the required position.

I hope I explained well enough so other can use this answer if ever in such situation, and if not, just comment and I will be glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is by design and intended.   `lp-bg.png` is the background image of your `li.block1`.  Your `<img>` is an element of `<li class="block1">`.

Think of it this way -- `<li class="block1">` is your canvas... everything you add to it, you paint on top of that canvas.

Perhaps you need to switch the images each element is displaying.

Comment: the li.block1 image should stay on top of `<li><a><img>`... but it doesn't for some reason. It never happened before to me, lol

Comment: I will do a screenshot and post it so you can see

Comment: @w0rldart: Why would the `background-image` of the container show up on top of the `img` element that's inside the container (i.e. in the *foreground*)? You seem to want and expect the opposite of the correct behavior.

Comment: because what `background-image` contains is a ribbon effect with some text on it, and I need to display it on top of the li (including the image)

Answer (score 0):

I think the first one is overruling the second one. You could try to give the second one another name. That's the only thing I can think of right now.

Comment: it has nothing to do, the first one in what I have tried wasn't the source of the problem. It's just that `#home #results li.block1`'s background image shows behind `<li><a><img>`

Comment: Okay but that's not actually what you said in the question. Maybe be a little bit more clear and post an screenshot? :)